# Angular 2 orderby column table

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

this is my simple pipe, for order alphabetically

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({name: 'orderBy'})
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(array: any[], args: string): any {
    array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      if (a < b) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a > b) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
    return array;
  }
}
```

and this is the component where i use it

```
<div class="row page-titles">
  <div class="col-md-5 align-self-center">
    <h3 class="text-themecolor">Agente</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7 align-self-center">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <li class="breadcrumb-item">
        <a href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="breadcrumb-item">
        <a href="">Agenti</a>
      </li>
      <li class="breadcrumb-item">
        <a href="">Gestione account</a>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title"><span class="lstick"></span>Lista agenti</h4>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th (click)="ordinamento = ['+nome']">Nome</th>
              <th>Cognome</th>
              <th>Indirizzo</th>
              <th>Numero di telefono</th>
              <th>Stato</th>
              <th>Modifica</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let agent of agents | orderBy: ordinamento">
              <td>{{agent.nome}}</td>
              <td>{{agent.cognome}}</td>
              <td>{{getFullAddress(agent)}}</td>
              <td>{{agent.numeroTelefono}}</td>
              <td><span class="badge badge-success" [ngClass]="getLabelStatusAgent(agent)">{{agent.status}}</span></td>
              <td><button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" [routerLink]="['dettaglio/' + agent.id]">Modifica</button></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ordinamento is an empty array.
I tried to order by name, but when i clicked th nothing happens.
I'll add an icon (two arrow) and my purpose is to ascending/descending ordering  the field (clicking th).

Comment: What is your question? Whats not working?

Comment: When i click name, i want to order the column name

Answer (score 0):

I had to fork your project to understand better the question.
You're using the pipe in the wrong way. You are passing it the array to iterate and the entity to execute the order by with, but you're not considering the entity at all.

Let me modify a little bit your project:

```
<th (click)="ordinamento = 'nome'">Nome</th>
```

The html should just pass the entity name without nothing else.

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({name: 'orderBy'})
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(array: any[], entity: string): any {
    array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      if (a[entity] < b[entity]) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a[entity] > b[entity]) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
    return array;
  }
}
```

And the pipe should sort the array by the entity you pass to it. You will never sort an array of objects like you did if you do not specify the entity to sort by.

I am sorry, i tried to explain myself as best as i could.
I hope i helped you! greets